# Multi-touch with Hammer.js

Tags: cordova, multi-touch

I have being trying to do a multitouch listener. But it doesn't work and in the documentation there is not very much to learn from.
I have seen that the multitouch only works inside canvas. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use hammer.js multi touch in cordova applications,.
refer this documentation http://www.appliness.com/multitouch-with-hammer-js/

```
var touches = event.gesture.touches || [event.originalEvent];// instaed of event.originalEvent.touches || [event.originalEvent];
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will take my time with the Zoom and Drag example